# How to click on Android Button then go to google play apps

Tags: android

I wonder how to make a android button can click and redirect user to google play.

Example: I want send user to android apps(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theopen.android) after user click on Button in my activity.

How to do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
   view=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.w);
   view.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com");
}
});
```

Comment: This is good for opening inside your app in ahead prepared WebView. But the question was about going to the GooglePlay app. (probably in order to update this app, or recommend another one).

Answer (score 49):

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.theopen.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open your application in **Play store**(android market)

Comment: You forgot to tell, that you need to replace the string in url: "com.theopen.android"  for your concrete package URL. 
So for instance in my case, i have: package com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile;
So I need to put "com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile" as trailing URL string

Answer (score 7):

To redirect to google play, we need to check whether the mobile already have play store app, if not google play should be opened in browser.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.app"));
try{
     startActivity(intent);
}
catch(Exception e){                 intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.app"));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name here");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here what I did and it works even if there is no application (like GooglePlay) to take the first intent. In such case there is another attempt to open GooglePlay in web browser - there should be at least default:

```
   mOkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile")); // Open precisely @link SmartBooks
            boolean tryAgain = false; // Flag to denote that normal attempt to launch GooglePlay update failed

            try
            {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                tryAgain = true;
            }

            if (!tryAgain) return;

            // Try to launch GooglePlay with SB in browser !
            try
            {
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mEmailView.setError("Unable to run app update automatically. Please run it from GooglePlay manualy.");
                mEmailView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_UP);
            }

            // No need to exit the app, as it already exits
            //finishAffinity();  // this requires  API level > 16
            //finish();
            //System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```