# How to open google play store with button click

Tags: android

hello I am working on my own launcher that has a button that says "Google Play" what I want it to do is when the user clicks this button it takes them to the google play store home page NOT to a specific app page

heres my code:

```
  /** Called when the user clicks the play button */
    public void play(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.vending","what goes here??"));
        intent.putExtra("grace", "Hi");
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Thanks way in advance

Regards

Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: That gave me a crash when I tried it any other advice?

Comment: just get a try, it work for me, use com.android.vending as edited

Comment: You forgot to tell, that you need to replace the string in url: "com.theopen.android" for your concrete package URL. So for instance in my case, i have: package com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile; So I need to put "com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile" as trailing URL string

Answer (score 9):

Some other people have got the same problem:
[How to click on Android Button then go to google play apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609757/how-to-click-on-android-button-then-go-to-google-play-apps)

```
public void play(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.theopen.android"));
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

*Code idea from the answer from user "[MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1289716/mac)".*

Comment: that works but it says item not found what am i doing wrong??

Comment: @ChrisDeBrodie1335
You need to replace the string in url: "com.theopen.android" for your concrete package URL. So for instance in my case, i have: package com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile; So I need to replace for: "com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile"

Comment: Does not work with API <= 17 .. Throws Exception "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile }"
On API >= 21 it works fine.
Did not try inbetween.

Comment: My other comment in this thread should be:

Does not work with Emulators  without GoogleApi included !
It throws Exception "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.sbm.bc.smartbooksmobile }"
On API = 21 with GoogleApi  it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.danhgia);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.ucnon.truyen"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try entering an empty query instead of a package name? I must say I haven't tried it myself either

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this Code **button or nav item or any clickable action**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=yourpackegName")); /// here "yourpackegName" from your app packeg Name 
        startActivity(intent);
```