# How do I set Link when onBackPressed Called

Tags: android

I'm new Android developer and I want to set **Link for my 3rd Button** when onBackPressed Called. Rest of 2 Are working fine. But I want, when Click "**More Apps**" its redirect to Google Play Store. How do I do that? Please Help me Expert Developer.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_close);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setNeutralButton("More Apps", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        alert.setTitle("Listview Application");
        alert.setMessage("Do you want to close?");
        alert.setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate: [How to navigate to google play store on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609757/how-to-click-on-android-button-then-go-to-google-play-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert.setNeutralButton("More Apps", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"More Apps Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.stackoverflow.comenter code here/"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Mate @bQuiet. It's working awesome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to this method.

```
public void openMoreApps(String playStoreUrl) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(playStoreUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```